# Raspistill doesn't work well in low light

Tags: camera, raspicam

I am taking photos every hour during the day. Photos at night are very underexposed as you can see in my example.
Here's the part of the python script that matters

```
import os
os.system("raspistill -t 2000 -md 2 -ex auto -awb off -awbg 1.5,1.45 -ISO 100 -o photo.jpg")
```

[image: Photo at 5 am south hemisphere]

Exif data:

> Make                            : RaspberryPi
> Camera Model Name               : RP_imx219
> Exposure Time                   : 1/15
> F Number                        : 2.0
> Exposure Program                : Aperture-priority AE
> ISO                             : 100
> Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
> Flash                           : No Flash
> Exif Image Width                : 3280
> Exif Image Height               : 2464
> **Exposure Mode                   : Auto**
> White Balance                   : Auto
> Megapixels                      : 8.1
> **Shutter Speed                   : 1/15**
> Focal Length                    : 3.0 mm
> Light Value                     : 5.9

Manual tests showed me that 2 seconds was a good ss value for exposure.
1/15" is 5 points of underexposure
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Under low clight conditions, the required shutter speed cannot be determined automatically. You have to specify the -ss option, with the shutter time in microseconds following.

Comment: Where in the manual says that? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md

Comment: Nowhere, but others had the same problem: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/263

Comment: More than two years ago. Maybe a software update? Hardware is newer. (don't realize why down vote)